# Cognito Custom Message with HTML Tag

Tags: html, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am sending Cognito Verification Link with a message that have HTML Tags.

I am trying to send the codeParameter inside a custom button:

```
 <div align="center" class="button-container center" style="padding-right:5px;padding-left:5px;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
  <a href="{####}" target="_blank" style="display:block;text-decoration:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;text-align:center;color:#323232;background-color:#ffc400;border-radius:25px;-webkit-border-radius:25px;-moz-border-radius:25px;max-width:210px;width:160px;width:auto;border-top:0 solid transparent;border-right:0 solid transparent;border-bottom:0 solid transparent;border-left:0 solid transparent;padding-top:5px;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:25px;font-family:'Droid Serif',Georgia,Times,'Times New Roman',serif;mso-border-alt:none">
    <span style="font-size:16px;line-height:32px">Verify your email</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

But It sends this to me:

```
x-webdoc://9166B278-3889-4E59-A9E2-F88FD6970944/%7B##</a>
```

Instead of a link like this:

```
https://xxxxx.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/confirmUser?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&user_name=marcuspdg22&confirmation_code=244905
```

Comment: I was wondering if you ended up using the solution in the answer, I'm trying to do the same thing. How did you manage in the end?

Comment: @8vius, yes, the solution of the answer worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here are some tips that worked for me:

- Don't use full HTML page, just put the HTML code included in your `<body></body>`
- Javascript, Jquery, etc is not supported
- Inside your UserPool console, go to Message Customizations and change your verification type to **Code**. After that, just create a confirmation link with this code in your lambda trigger like `'https://{yourUserPoolDomain/confirmUser?client_id={yourClientId}&user_name=' + event.userName + '&confirmation_code=' + event.request.codeParameter`

You can put this confirmation link inside a `href` tag. Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 7):

I managed (after many hours of trial and error) to send an HTML email to the user using a [Custom Message Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html).

**Step 1:** As @Olavo mentioned, change the verification type to code.

**Step 2:** Under user pool -> triggers, set a lambda function that will customize your email

**Step 3:** Create a lambda function like mine below

Be aware that you might not have the user attribute name. You can just delete that.

Here's my full Lambda function with a button like yours:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.verificationEmail = async (event, context, callback) => {

  const template = (name, link) => `<html>
    <body style="background-color:#333; font-family: PT Sans,Trebuchet MS,sans-serif; ">
      <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; background-color: #fff; font-size: 1.2rem; font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;line-height: 19px;" align="center">
        <div style="padding: 20;">
            <p style="Margin-top: 20px;Margin-bottom: 0;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="Margin-top: 20px;Margin-bottom: 0;">&nbsp;</p>
            <img style="border: 0;display: block;height: auto; width: 100%;max-width: 373px;" alt="Animage" height="200" width="300"  src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" />
            <p style="Margin-top: 20px;Margin-bottom: 0;">&nbsp;</p>
            <h2
                style="font-size: 28px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0;font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; color: #000;font-size: 24px;line-height: 32px;text-align: center;">Hi ${name}</h2>
            <p style="Margin-top: 20px;Margin-bottom: 0;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="Margin-top: 20px;Margin-bottom: 0;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px; color: #000">Click the link below to confirm your signup. Cheers!</p>
            <p style="Margin-top: 20px;Margin-bottom: 0;">&nbsp;</p>

                <div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;Margin-top: 24px;">
                    <div style="Margin-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;">
                        <a
                            style="border-radius: 4px;display: block;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 24px;padding: 12px 24px 13px 24px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none !important;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color: #ffffff !important;box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);background-color: #3b5998;font-family: PT Sans, Trebuchet MS, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.05rem;"
                            href="${link}">CLICK HERE TO VERIFY YOUR EMAIL</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>`

  const link = `https://<yourUserPoolDomain>/confirmUser?client_id=${event.callerContext.clientId}&user_name=${event.userName}&confirmation_code=`
  const name = event.request.userAttributes.name.split(" ")[0]

  if (event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_SignUp") {

    event.response = {
        emailSubject: "AweseomeApp2000 | Confirm your email",
        emailMessage: template(name, link + event.request.codeParameter)
    }
  }

  callback(null, event);

};
```

And here is a screenshot of how the email will look in gmail:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that we were using `react.email` library for generating email templates, for some reason `<Preview>` tag was causing errors while uploading any HTML template , after removing it everything worked fine even with uploading opening and closing `<HTML>` tag